# PHP Unable to increment any value but the last added to the array

Tags: php

I am using incrementing/decrementing to change the quantity demanded of items in my cart. However, this only seems to be working for the last value/row added to the array. e.g. if I add 1 item to the cart, incrementing ($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]++) works fine. However if I add a second item to the cart, incrementing only works for the latest added item and not the first added, and the same can be said for any additional added items.

Can someone please indicate where I have gone wrong and help me fix my code please?

I am echoing using the $value at the end contained within a foreach loop.

Here is my code (cart.php):

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}
$total = 0;
$page = 'cart';

//Database connection info (Using MySQLi) removed for security

if(isset($_GET['comic_id'])){ 
    $comic_id = $_GET['comic_id'];
} else {
    $comic_id = NULL;}

$action = $_GET['action'];

if($comic_id && !productExists($comic_id)) {
    die("We apologise, but we can't seem to find the comic you were looking for!!!");
}

switch($action) {
    case "add":
        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]++;

        } else {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id] = 1;
            }
    break;  
    case "remove":
        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]--;}
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]);
    break;  
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); 
        session_destroy();
    break;  
}

require('header.php');
require('sidebar.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id])){

    echo "<table border=\"0\" padding=\"10\" width=\"80%\">";
    echo "<td colspan=\"1\" align=\"left\"><a href=\"title.php\">Continue Shopping</a></div>";
    echo "<td colspan=\"6\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Crystal Fusion: Are you sure you wish to empty your cart?');\">Empty Cart</a></td>";                      
    echo "<tr height=\"20px\">";
    echo "<tr height=\"20px\">";
    echo "<td align=center>Image</td><td align=center>Title</td><td align=center>Description</td><td colspan=3 align=center>Copies (+/-)</td><td align=center>Price</td>";
    echo "<tr height=\"20px\">";


    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $comic_id => $qty) {   

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT title, description, cost, image_thumbnail
                FROM comic 
                WHERE comic_id = %d;",$comic_id);

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            list($name, $description, $price, $image_thumbnail) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

            $cost = $price * $qty; 
            $total = $total + $cost;

            $cost = number_format($cost,2);
            $total = number_format($total,2);
            $description =  substr($description, 0, 250);

            echo "<br><tr>";
            echo "<td width=\"10px\" align=\"center\"><img height=100 align=center src=\"$image_thumbnail\">";
            echo "<td align=\"center\">$name</td>";
            echo "<td width=\"40%\" align=\"center\">$description...<a href=comic_dyn.php?comic_id=$comic_id>More Info</td>";
            echo "<td width=\"30px\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=add&comic_id=$comic_id\">+<br></a><td align=\"center\">$qty <td width=\"20px\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&comic_id=$comic_id\">-</a></td>";
            echo "<td align=\"right\">$$cost</td>";
            echo "</tr>";           
        }

    }

    echo "<br><tr><tr height=100px>";
    echo "<td><td><td colspan=\"4\" align=\"right\">Total:</td>";
    echo "<td width=\"60px\" align=\"right\">$$total</td>"; 
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"7\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"checkout_html.php\">Proceed to Checkout</a>";
    echo "<tr height=\"50px\">";
    echo "</table>";
}else{

    echo "Your cart is currently empty.";
    echo "<br><br><td colspan=\"1\" align=\"left\"><a href=\"title.php\">Continue Shopping</a></div>";

}

$_SESSION['invoice'][$comic_id]=$name . " " . $qty . " " . $price;

foreach ($_SESSION['invoice'] as $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";}

function productExists($comic_id) {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM comic WHERE comic_id = %d;", $comic_id);
    return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > 0;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$comic_id` is set correctly?

Comment: how do you mean? I am able to echo the $name, $qty & $price for each added value ($comic_id) in the array. However, unable to increment $qty for any except the last added value.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: thanks for the heads up Waleed, was intending upon doing that later. But doesn't really assist me with my question in any way what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do foreach on your switch statement to add/remove the value from your each Items. Like that

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $comic_id => $qty) {
switch($action) {
    case "add":
        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]++;

        } else {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id] = 1;
            }
    break;  
    case "remove":
        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]--;}
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]);
    break;  
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); 
        session_destroy();
    break;  
}


}
```

Comment: I am unsure that a foreach will work if the variables aren't defined yet?

Notice: Undefined index: cart in C:\wamp\www\cart.php on line 28
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\cart.php on line 28
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\www\cart.php on line 109
Notice: Undefined variable: qty in C:\wamp\www\cart.php on line 109
Notice: Undefined variable: price in C:\wamp\www\cart.php on line 109

Comment: I have added if(!isset) to get rid of the errors, but am unable to add anything to the array anymore.